# Не работает $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

товарищи! Задача проста — скрывать два метатега на страницах, где они не нужны. Вот такая конструкция, почему-то не работает (задумывалось, что она будет выводить метатеги только на страницах, если их адрес совпадает с шаблоном /post/{id}):

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/post/') : ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?= $description ?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?= $keywords ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Так же, не работает иной код, который призван выводит разные блоки меню для сайта и админки. Он всё правильно делает, если адрес /admin, но если он, скажем, /admin/writePost, то, выводится стандартное меню. Вот такой код:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) : ?>
    <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/admin') : ?>
         <a class="alogo" href="/admin">Admin</a>
         <?php require_once('amenu.php'); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
         <a class="logo" href="/">Главная</a>
         <?php require_once('menu.php'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Почему Вы напрямую сравниваете? Используйте функции нахождения подстроки в строке, например strpos, как вариант.

Comment: И с каких пор `/post/42` стало равно `/post/`?

Comment: u_mulder, я не утверждаю :) А как следует здесь поступить?

Comment: DaemonHK, а вы не могли бы привести пример?

Comment: Следует открыть гугол и поискать "php найти подстроку в строке"

Comment: @u_mulder Ура! Не только меня бесят тупые вопросы.
Автор, в идеале - preg_match() тебя спасёт. Но там регурярки. Навскидку, должно быть что-то типа:
/\/admin\/.*/i

Comment: Сообразил: <?php if (preg_match('/\/post\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) : ?>, а вот <?php if (preg_match('/\/admin\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) : ?> не вполне работает, всё нормально, когда вот так /admin/{id}, а когда просто /admin, тогда не работает :(

Comment: Всё, вот это работает <?php if (preg_match('/\/admin|admin\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) : ?>